# Como ir para o topo de uma Activity no Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-eclipse

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Java para Android que é um **Quiz** e toda vez que vou para a próxima questão eu visualizo os *radio buttons* e gostaria de posicionar a tela no topo, para que o usuário possa iniciar a leitura.

[image: tela1]

[image: tela2]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ir para o topo de sua `ScrollView` "de forma suave":

```
suaScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
```

Ou:

```
suaScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
```